# When a jet engine propels an aircraft forward, where does the thrust force on aircraft act?

Tags: finite-element-method, thrust

I am trying to model the mount structure of an aircraft onto which a jet engine is attached, in Finite Element Analysis. Since I am only concerned about the local mount structure, I have isolated it and that is the sole part in my FEA model.
I want to understand that how should I make use of the max thrust force into my FEA.

We know that when the jet engine produces thrust, it produces acceleration and the net thrust is neutralized by the inertia of the whole of aircraft. So the mount structure onto which the jet engine is attached, it will only be subjected to inertial forces of the jet engine?

But at the same time, there exists a net thrust force which is propelling the aircraft forward.
Do I also need to input this thrust force at well, at the same locations onto the mount where the engine is attached, or not? Yes or no, please elaborate thank you.

Comment: Why do you say that the *net thrust is neutralized by the inertia of the whole of aircraft*? I would have thought, that the aerodynamic drag plays a role, at least in the steady state. OR are you only thinking about take off?

Comment: F=MA.  At max thrust the plane accelerates (to max I guess, most planes have Vmax at less than full engine speed).  For a given steady state speed, engine thrust = air drag on the aircraft.

Comment: Assuming this is a real-world engine mount, it has some well-defined interface points between (1) the mount and the engine and (2) the mount and the aircraft. The only thing the mount "knows about" is the forces on those interface points. Also, note that in most real engine mounts the two sets of interface connection are each intentionally designed to be *statically determinate.* which makes finding the applied loads much easier.

Comment: @alephzero to make it more explicit I would add **and moments** to "*The only thing the mount "knows about" is the forces **and moments** on those interface points.*".

Comment: thrust force will be on the axis of the turbofan. not the engine mount point (although it's close). front to back location doesn't matter, as long as you are on the correct axis

Comment: I believe the engine generates thrust to propel the airplane forward, the repellant force from the thrust is handled by the propeller inside the engine that is independent of the engine housing, thus the engine mount (connection) will not be affected by the thrust. In addition to the function of moving the plane forward, the thrust needs to be large enough to overcome the air drag. Similar to the design of a car, air drag is important, but it's not the reason and sole focus of the design.

Comment: @r13, if the rotor weren't attached to the engine housing it would fly out the front of the engine.

Comment: @TigerGuy Please see the attached article in my answer. I know the shaft of the gas turbine has a support mechanism that does not involve turbine housing. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Guys, lets just assume that the aircraft is moving in vacuum with no air whatsoever, for simplicity. So we can make the air drag = 0 N.

Comment: @alephzero, exactly my point. Only thing that the mount knows about are the net forces/moments acting on the connection points, after passing through the body of the mount. But my question is a little bit different. I want to know what value should I input inside my FEA? I will make use of the acceleration definitely, because there exists a net thrust and mount has to experience the inertial forces coming from its mass as well as the mass of engine attached to it. I am confused if I should add any extra force inside my model? Like max thurst, or a fraction of it, or something else.

Comment: I am fixing the locations on mount where it is connected to aircraft in my FEA. Apart from inputting the acceleration coming from 2nd law of Newton, I was also thinking I should use this equation for force to be inputted  : F = Fmax - Fme. Here, Fmax is max thrust generated from the engine and Fme is inertial forces generated from mount + engine. This F is the net force which should be overcome by the rest of the aircraft parts inertial forces. In this way, the mount itself will experience the inertial forces because of its own mass as well as engine, and also this F will pass through it.

Comment: @NMech In theory yes, but in practice I've never seen an engine mount that transmits bending moments directly. Cantilever beams are an inefficient way to use material compared with a truss structure. Often that doesn't matter, but in aerospace minimizing weight is always a good idea!  The typical interface to an engine mount (ignoring failsafe features etc) is 6 pin-jointed rods that transmit loads and moments in any direction in 3D space. (Also the interface has to handle thermal expansion etc, without creating "thermal fights" that raise stress levels).

Comment: @RameezUlHaq The inertia loads *created by the mass of the mount itself* will be negligible compared with the thrust loads. Just assume the resultant loads on the engine and airframe sides are equal and opposite.

Comment: @NMech For example look at this to see just how minimalist the *load-carrying* parts of an engine mount can be. https://www.condoraviation.co.uk/2017/10/20/cessna-120-radial/ Most of what *looks like* part of the engine mounts on a typical plane is not load-carrying at all, but just aerodynamic fairings, etc.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq "*Guys, lets just assume that the aircraft is moving in vacuum with no air whatsoever*", a plane cannot fly in the absence of air. The air is generating the lift required to keep it up.

Comment: @NMech, I just said ignore the air drag since the drag is acting on the exterior surface of the aircraft and the mount (bearing the thrust load) is usually inside the aircraft. So the mount doesn't have any relation to the drag whatsoever. But ofcourse, the thrust has to produced in such a manner that it overcomes the total drag, otherwise it won't accelerate at all.

Comment: @alephzero, yeah I agree with you. Using a cantilever beam is actually an inefficient way since that means that beam is resisting the moment and hence resulting in more stress at the region where it is attached to the aircraft itself, which means more weight at that local region. If we want to not make use of cantilever beam, then a truss like structure is usually used atleast on small aircrafts which doesn't resist bending moments at the connection points with the aircraft.

Comment: @alephzero, Moreover, you mentioned about the resultant loads; I am still unclear what resultant load should be applied at the mount? Max thrust? Max thrust - inertial loads (coming from mount and engine)? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

The thrust force acts on the axle bearings that support the compressor stage shaft of the turbine. That reaction force is conveyed out to the engine mounts which are in turn bolted to the airframe.

Answer (score 3):

I think the thrust is generally applied as show on the top part of the following image.

[image]

If you are trying to apply the force on the mount, then the same force is applied, however you need to add a bending moment. The bending moment should be equal to the product of the thrust T, times the distance between the axis of the axle and the mount points.

Comment: Well, yes. But most of the times its not that simple to calculate the moment by hand. FEA softwares have the feature to directly input a thrust force at any remote location and the resulting moments that are developed are calculated automatically by the FEA solver itself and applied onto the respective parts.

Comment: And also, I don't know why my question was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

At the start-up of the motion of the airplane the thrust mostly goes to overcome the static and then dynamic friction of tires so we need to consider the moment with respect to the distance of the center of the jet engines to the runway (for your design).

Then the thrust goes mostly to overcome the lift-induced drag and parasite drag. And a fraction of the thrust goes to create acceleration, except in fighter jets where a considerate amount of thrust goes to acceleration and is applied to the center of the mass of the fighter jet.

The take-off time thrust in a jetliner causes two moments:

One due to the moment arm between the jets and aerodynamic center of drag and another moment torque to the center of mass.

But later in level flight, the entire thrust becomes equal to the drag ( combination of parasite drag and induced drag). here is a diagram from Wikipedia.

.

[image: drag forcees]

In jetliners like the Boeing 737 max, the weight to thrust ratio is 6-6.5 [source](https://modernairliners.com/boeing-737/boeing-737-max/) with a max acceleration of roughly 1.8m/s which is not much compared to drag forces and friction forces.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Jet Engine**

[image]

Copied from https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/UEET/StudentSite/engines.html

**2) Internal of a Jet Engine and Mounting Mechanism**

[image]
[image]